# Showing a extended real valued function is measurable, problem dividing by $0$ and $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

Suppose $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ if x is not $0$, and $f(x)= \infty$ if $x=0$. How do I show that f is borel measurable? I was thinking of writing f as $f(x)= \frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x) + g(x) 1_{\{x=0\}}$ where $g(x)= \infty$ for all x. Then as  $\{(a,\infty]: a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a set of generators for the borel sigma algebra of the extended reals, clearly 1/x is borel measurable, and so is each indicator and finally g as well as the inverse image of any such interval is all real numbers.However, what bothers me is the fact that $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ does not even make sense at $x=0$ as the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined there. Also what bothers me is g(x) will be infinity when x is not 0 but the indicator will be 0, and we will have $\infty$ times 0. Could anyone clear things up for me?

Answer (score 1):

You show something more general, namely that if you have 2 functions $f$ and $g$ ,$f$ being mesurable and $μ([g\neq f])=0$ (the points that $g$ differs from $f$ has measure 0) then g is also measurable. To do this compare the sets $[f\leq a]$ and $[g\leq a]$. Use the fact that Lebesgue measure is complete, namely that if a you have two sets $A$ measurble and $B$ and $μ(A\bigtriangleup B)=0$ then $B$ is measurable.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I need to show f is borel measurable though.

Comment: Of course. But, since $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}-{0}$ it is also measurable there. In general , notice that since $f(0)=\infty$ for every real $a$ we have $[\frac{1}{x} \leq a]=[f \leq  a]$  and $[\frac{1}{x}<\infty]\cup {0} = [f< \infty ] $ so $[f<a]$ measurable for all $a$. In my answer I suggested a more general plan of action :)

Answer (score 1):

> However, what bothers me is the fact that $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ does not even make sense at $x=0$ as the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined there. Also what bothers me is $g(x)$ will be infinity when $x$ is not $0$ but the indicator will be $0$, and we will have $\infty$ times $0$.

Note that you are actually using $f(x) 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ here, so it will be well-defined: in the space $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=[-\infty,\infty]$ we have by definition (this definition is usual in measury theory) that $0\cdot \infty=0$, so both $f(x) 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ and $g(x) 1_{\{x = 0\}} (x)$ are well-defined.

Comment: Thanks The Phenotype, I don't get how the problem of  $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x) $ at x=0 is fixed though? I have a formula for f(x), and so if I plug in 0, I must plug in 0 everywhere in its formula, including in the $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: I guess indicator functions have priority and anything they are attached to takes a value only if the indicator is 1?

Comment: $f(0)=\infty$, so $f(0) 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (0)=\infty\cdot 0=0$ because $f(x)$ is defined as $f(x)=\infty$ if $x=0$.

Comment: Yes I agree but how is $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ as a function of x the same as $f(x) 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ ? f(x) only has meaning after defining it in terms of $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ and h(x) ?

Comment: No, the way $f(x)$ is defined does not consider what happens for $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$. However, $\frac{1}{x} 1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)$ does consider what happens for $\frac{1}{x}$ at $x=0$, which is a problem, because it cannot be defined as $\infty$ or $-\infty$ at $x=0$ (unless you redefine the product of a function with the indicator function). That's why you should write $f(x)=f(x)1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)+f(x) 1_{\{x=0\}} (x)=f(x)1_{\{x \neq 0\}} (x)+g(x) 1_{\{x=0\}} (x)$.

Comment: Thanks, I still am confused, how can you define $f(x)= f(x) 1_{\{x\neq 0\}}(x) + g(x) 1_{\{x=0\}} (x)$? What is the function f(x) on the right hand side?

Comment: It seems like a circular definition.

Comment: For $x=0$, we have $f(0) 1_{\{x= 0\}}(0)=\infty\cdot 1=\infty=\infty\cdot 1=g(0) 1_{\{x= 0\}}(0)$, because both $f$ and $g$ are well-defined as $\infty$ in $x=0$. For $x\neq 0$, we have $f(x) 1_{\{x= 0\}}(x)=\infty\cdot 0=0=\infty\cdot 0=g(x) 1_{\{x= 0\}}(x)$. So $f 1_{\{x= 0\}}=g 1_{\{x= 0\}}$. The definition is not circular, because piecewise functions are **not** defined as products of indicator functions with the corresponding functions. **If** the functions are well-defined, then you can express them with indicator functions. This is not the case with $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: I see what you're saying now! So f(x)= f(x) 1_{\{x\neq 0}}(x) + g(x) 1_{\{x\neq 0}}(x) . Now obviously the indicator functions are measurable and so is g. But then I cant finish the proof that f is borel measurable that way as f is in the right hand side. Any thoughts how to show f is borel measurable then? Thanks.

Comment: $h(x)= f(x) 1_{\{x\neq 0\}}(x)$ can be shown to be Borel measurable by using the set of generators as noted in your question. All these comments were only to discuss the nuance and problems of the indicator function, so I suggest you carefully write out what $h$ is. Also, it is a formal gesture of gratitude to accept answers, and I recommend you do it for your older questions that you feel have been completely answered, because not doing so might come off as rude.